# Why would the Google cache and Googlebot not render images?

Tags: seo, javascript, angular.js

I’m auditing an e-commerce website but I’m having really difficult time figuring out why Googlebot can’t render the pages correctly. When I check the cache of the pages I see that Googlebot couldn’t render much of the content.

A url for instance: `/kadin-deri-ceket-35`

[image: what users see vs what googlebot see]

I have an guess about what might be the issue but I’m not sure:
The URL has escaped fragment version (in this case the ugly URL is `/kadin-deri-ceket-35?_escaped_fragment_=&`) but Googlebot doesn’t request it because original URL doesn’t contain a `#!hash` fragment or meta tag `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

Or maybe it might be due to robots.txt has a line which disallows `/Handlers/` (I don’t know what it is).

[image: handlers]

Comment: You need to place your GA code before the closing `</head>`.
You have it placed above your meta data.

Comment: Googlebot just stopped crawling `escaped_fragment`s altogether: https://searchengineland.com/google-will-stop-crawling-old-ajax-crawling-scheme-q2-2018-287653

Comment: Have you used the "Fetch as Google" tool from Google Search Console?   The Google cache isn't necessarily what Googlebot sees.   Fetch as Google will do a better job of showing you how much of the site Googlebot is able to view.